# Node.js program does not stop reading from stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read user input from stdin, in my case, two inputs entered on separate lines. However, when I run the following code (`node program.js`), it allows me to enter the first value, then I click `enter` and type in the second value, but when I click `enter`, it does not run the rest of my program. How do I tell it to stop reading and proceed?

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
var input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (chunk) {
    input += chunk;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {  
    lines = input.split("\n");
    var numVals = lines[0];
    process.stdout.write(numVals + "\n");
    var vals = lines[1];
    process.stdout.write(vals+"\n");
});
```

Comment: Added `process.on('SIGINT', function(){
 console.log('Got SIGINT. Press Control-D to exit.'); 
});` and now I can stop it with Ctrl+C followed by Ctrl+D, but it prints D

Answer (score 3):

[Readable Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) expect an EOT (End of transmission) character before it triggers an `"end"` event. In bash this can be done using CTRL+D. If you want to explicitly stop after 2 line breaks, try this:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");

var input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (chunk) {

    input += chunk;

    var lines = input.split("\n");

    //If there have been 2 line breaks
    if (lines.length > 2) {

        //Stop reading input
        process.stdin.pause();

        //Process data
        var numVals = lines[0];
        process.stdout.write(numVals + "\n");

        var vals = lines[1];
        process.stdout.write(vals+"\n");
    }
});
```

You are re-inventing the wheel a bit though. Line input is typically handled using the [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) or [`prompt`](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt) modules.

Comment: Thanks. I actually took pieces from the [api site](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html). I added the SIGINT and I can Ctrl+C, followed by Ctrl+D and the rest of my script runs. I will try your recommendation though because the above edit actually makes it print D for some reason.